# Svn on two isolated networks?

Tags: svn

We have an isolated lab network that can never connect to the internet / the main LAN.  We have developers working on both networks - on the LAN and on the Lab net.  The repositories will be fairly large, several GB. How can we synchronize two separate repositories in SVN using DVDs?

Comment: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/ ?

Comment: Indeed, you could enable the repository replication between these sites. However two VisualSVN Server instances will have to communicate with each other. This is the easiest and most effective approach. Other ones like those @lazybadger described are not really helpful in practice because they don't support any collaboration between teams.

Answer (score 1):

- Easy way: exchange of full dumps of repositories (`svnadmin dump`+`svnadmin load`). Long time, big size, easy workflow (easy automation)
- Harder way: exchange of incremental dumps. For every repo repo-admin have to know new, local revisions for including into dump. Shorter time and size of dump, more complex workflow (mostly handwork)
- Exotic way: two Mercurial repos (+hgsubversion) on USB-stick. clone SVN, pull FOREIGN, rebase --svn, push SVN, delete hg-repos (all operations performed twice in cycle)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [VisualSVN Server Multisite Repository Replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/)